# How to hide Text on overflow in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-8

I am creating custom file chooser in JavaFX. Here is a button group for it:

[image]

And here is an fxml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<GridPane hgap="5.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
          minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.131">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="200.0"
                           prefWidth="200.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="25.0"
                           prefWidth="25.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="25.0"
                           prefWidth="25.0"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
                   minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                   style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets/>
            </GridPane.margin>
            <children>
                <Text stroke="BLACK" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"
                      text="Chosen file name" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                    <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0"/>
                    </StackPane.margin>
                </Text>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
        <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0"
                   style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                   GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="x"/>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
        <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0"
                   style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;" GridPane.columnIndex="2"
                   GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="..."
                      StackPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
    </padding>
</GridPane>
```

When a user clicks on [image] button (I am using Text as a button), it will show file chooser. After file chosen in should show file name. Everything works fine, but there is a problem when a file name is too long, the text is overflowing.

[image]

I want the text to be ended with "..." at the end instead of overflowing, and the size should not extend its parent size.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) instead. This automatically uses a ellipsis if the text gets too long for the available area. In contrast to `Text` it extends `Region` and therefore can be resized by the parent layout:

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

...
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
           minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0"
           style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets/>
    </GridPane.margin>
    <children>
        <Label textFill="BLACK" text="Chosen file name" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT"
               ellipsisString="..." textOverrun="ELLIPSIS" wrapText="false">
            <StackPane.margin>
                <Insets left="5.0"/>
            </StackPane.margin>
        </Label>
    </children>
</StackPane>
...
```

Comment: Thanks very much.